# Why does sandboxie require admin privileges when it runs a program that requires it (for example installing a software)?

Tags: sandboxie

Shouldn't it just emulate the admin privileges like everything else? Why dose it actually require it?

Comment: Because it is not a virtual machine, it is a sandbox.  It does not emulate all functions from an operating system.  If a program wants direct access to something that it cannot provide, it needs to ask the operating system for permission just as it would outside of the sandbox.   Have you tried the sandbox built into windows 10?

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Wouldn't giving direct access to the program make a security hole though? And I have.

Comment: @Hormoz - There are significant differences between Windows Sandbox and Sandboxie.  Is this question about Sandboxie which has no emulation (nor virtualization) or Windows Sandboxie which uses virtualization?

Comment: @Ramhound Sandboxie, this has nothing to do with Windows Sandbox (I was just answering the above commenter's question). I am just wondering why sandboxie requires admin permissions,and whether that can cause a security problem.